# How do I detect changes to a Core Data document in iCloud on OS X before the document gets reloaded?

Tags: macos, core-data, icloud, nsdocument

I am currently working on an app that is document based on both OS X and iOS and uses Core Data. To make the documents the same on the two platforms I am using [BSManagedDocument](https://github.com/karelia/BSManagedDocument) on the OS X side.

If I launch the app on both platforms simultaneously and open the same document in each I can make changes on the OS X side and get two notifications on the iOS side (one when the document state goes to editing disabled and one when it returns to normal). I can easily use the second one as a trigger to update the UI allowing the iOS side to work as it should.

The problem is when I make a change on the iOS side. When this happens the document window gets re-opened (I've verified that `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` is getting called). In a simple app this is mostly just a hiccup (though one that needs to be removed) while in more complex apps I have seen this result in only a partial redraw of the window contents.

I tried registering for `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` but this notification never happens on either platform.

**Is there any way at all on OS X to be informed that changes have come in from iCloud so that the required updates can be made to the UI and then prevent the re-opening of the window?**

Comment: I filed a DTS for this. If I get an answer that can be shared I will add an answer so no one else has to file a DTS.

Answer (score 0):

Mike its not clear from your description whether you are using iCloud to synchronise transaction logs or whether you are placing the whole document in iCloud and synchronising the document.  If you are using transaction logs to synchronise the documents then its not clear what the 'editing disabled' notification is - this is not something that is useful for transaction log synchronisation.  For the latter you must open the store with the NSPersistentStoreUbiquityNameKey option set and this will cause Core Data to create transaction logs in iCloud and import logs from other devices.  You should then get import notifications.

A quick check in the iCloud container should confirm which approach you are using.  If you are using transaction logs then the iCloud container should look something like this:
[image]

You may want to look at the link below where I have posted some more detailed descriptions on how to create document based apps.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/.

Unfortunately the sample apps are not based on UIManagedDocument or NSPersistentDocument but if you look at the way they handle backup files you could probably use that approach to create a document based app with less hassle than using UIManagedDocument.

In addition you would use the same approach they use to get notified of synchronisation updates to then update the UI.  Both make extensive use of the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` import notification you don't seem to be getting to to merge changes and send messages to the UI views to update themselves.

Comment: I found the `presentedItemDidChange` method in the `NSFilePresenter` protocol that tells me when the document has been changed on disk and if I intercept it without calling super the window doesn't re-open. I'm sure there is lots of other behavior that I will have to duplicate myself if I stay this route though. I'll have a look at your link to see if there are better ideas I can incorporate from there. The biggest issue is having the documents live in <ubiquityContainer>/Documents so the user can delete them individually outside the app.